# Algorithms/Solvers for Hard Constrained Non-Linear Optimization Problems - Model Predictive Control Example

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, non-convex-optimization, model-predictive-control, non-smooth-optimization

I have an autonomous robotic swarm path planning/control problem where a set of "leader" robots have predefined (nontrivial) dynamics in the control set, and "follower" robots are subject to optimization in their control. $u_i = (u_{l_i}^T \  u_{f_i}^T)^T$ is a vector containing the predefined control efforts of the leaders $u_{l_i}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n_l}$ and the optimizable efforts of the followers $u_{f_i}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n_f}$, for each time step $i \in \{1,...,t\}$. Then $u_i \in R^N, N = n_l+n_f$. The control efforts $u_i$ may be stacked in

$$u = \begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ ... \\ u_t \end{pmatrix} \in R^{N*t}$$

The same process can be done for $u_l$ and $u_f$.

This is an optimization problem of the form
$$min_{u_f} \ \ ||u||^2 \\
s.t. \  G(x_i)u_i \geq 0 \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \dot{x}_i = u_i \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall i \in \{1,...,t\}
$$
where $G(x_i) \in \mathbb{R}^{NxN}$ is a very sensitive non-linear matrix function of the vector state $x_i$. This dynamical system has a single integrator dynamics $\dot{x}_i = u_i$ which was discretized using a simple forward Euler technique. This rendered examples with a few hundred optimization variables $u_{f}$. Also the examples explored seem to always require a good initial guess (that respects the constraint in all discretized steps), regardless of the selected solver, and can not be relaxed in tolerance.

I have tried fmincon solver in MATLAB with all its algorithms. The optimization fails, because the initial guess is "shrunk" with little regard for the constraint.

I could use fminsearch and CMA-ES by including the constraints inside the cost function (returning NaN or a high value). With this I could improve the initial guess, but it still seems far from an optimal configuration.

Is there some algorithm/solver worth exploring for this type of problem? Is there some way of exploiting the "consecutive choice" nature of the control vector $u_i$?

Analytical derivatives of G(x) are not available. No success using log or barrier methods

Comment: Since $u=0$ seems to be a solution to your problem I guess you are missing some additional constraints?

Comment: Have you tried to replace the inequality constraints with log or other barrier functions?

Comment: I did not have success using log methods

Comment: The question is quite unclear. It seems from your text description that you do *not* minimize over the whole $u$ vector but only over a part of it. So I guess the actual problem you are trying to solve is $\min_{u_f} \Vert u\Vert^2 \text{ s.t. }G(x)u\geq 0$ with $u=\begin{pmatrix}u_l^T&u_f^T\end{pmatrix}^T$ with $u_l$ the leader commands and $u_f$ the follower commands. This would make much more sense than your formulation because if you minimize over $u$ you can just take $u=0$ as unique global minimum. Can you confirm that my interpretation is correct? If so please update the question.

Comment: Sorry, that is exactly what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n_l$ be the number of leaders and $n_f$ the number of followers so that $u_l\in \mathbb{R}^{n_l},u_f\in \mathbb{R}^{n_f}$. The problem is

$$
\min_{u_f}\Vert u\Vert^2 \text{ s.t. } G(x)u\geq 0
$$

with $u=\begin{pmatrix}u_l\\u_f\end{pmatrix}$ and $G(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, $N=n_l+n_f$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^{N}$. We can rewrite the inequality term

$$
G(x)u = \begin{pmatrix}G_{11}(x)&G_{12}(x)\\G_{21}(x)&G_{22}(x)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_l\\u_f\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now use the fact that $u_l$ is given so you get:

$$
\begin{align}\tag{1}
A_1 u_f &\leq b_1\\
A_2 u_f &\leq b_2\\
\end{align}
$$
with
$$
\begin{align}
A_1&=-G_{12}(x) \\
A_2&=-G_{22}(x) \\
b_1&=G_{11}(x)u_l \\
b_2&=G_{21}(x)u_l \\
\end{align}
$$

You can stack $(1)$ together to get

$$
A u_f \leq b
$$

with

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}A_1\\A_2\end{pmatrix},b=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now consider the cost which is

$$
\Vert u\Vert^2 = u_f^Tu_f + u_l^Tu_l
$$

Since $u_l$ is given, it cannot be changed by the optimization. So it is just a constant offset of the objective and can be omitted for the minimization. So you end up with

$$
\begin{align} \tag{2}
\min_{u_f} \frac{1}{2}u_f^T Q u_f\\
\text{s.t. } A u_f \leq b
\end{align}
$$

This is just a [quadratic program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) in $u_f$ with $A$ and $B$ as defined above, $Q = 2I$ and $I$ the identity matrix of matching size.

So in every timestep you can insert $x$ into the matrices to get a quadratic program that you can then solve to get the optimal $u_f$ (assuming the quadratic program is feasible). In Matlab you could for example use the [quadprog](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) function for this.

Comment: This is a very good answer, yet it does not optimize over all timesteps. I guess my problem definition is still inexact.

Comment: After the edit, I think it is now a little easier to understand. You see, the main problem of why QP will not work is that $G(x_{i+1})$ depends on $u_i$, because of the integration in $\dot{x}_i = u_i$. I believe I have no alternative but to employ nonlinear, metaheuristic or other less elegant types of algorithms.